# Create new folders in loop

Tags: matlab

I have a folder contain numerous subfolder with names that goes as G####### (# is any number between 0-9).
I loaded all the subfolders name into a cell called main. For the new folder, if the previous folder start with G then it become I and the ###### behind it woluld also move one place above it, i.e 0->1 4->5 9->0 so on, but I don't know where I coded run, it is getting stuck in the loop.

```
for i = 3:name_size_main
    str = main{i};
    size_str = size(str);
    j = 1;
    while j ~= size_str(2)
        if strcmpi(j,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='I';
            j = j+1;
        elseif strcmpi(1,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='2';
            j = j+1;
        elseif strcmpi(2,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='3';
            j = j+1;
        elseif strcmpi(3,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='4';
            j = j+1;
        elseif strcmpi(4,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='5';
            j = j+1;
        elseif strcmpi(6,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='7';
            j = j+1;
        elseif strcmpi(8,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='9';
            j = j+1;
        elseif strcmpi(9,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='0';
            j = j+1;
        elseif strcmpi(0,str(j))==1
            file_name(j)='1';
            j = j+1;
        end
    end
    mkdir(file_Paths_main,file_name);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question in two parts – first by proposing a simple way of solving your overall problem, then next to examine the problems with your loop.

---

**Solving your problem**

A simple way of solving your overall problem is like so:

```
str = 'G102019'
file_name = char(str + 1)
file_name(str=='9') = '0'

file_name =

H213120
```

To understand this, note that each character has an associated number - e.g. capital 'A' is represented by number 65:

```
>> double('A')

ans =

    65
```

This number can be manipulated  and converted back to a character using `char`:

```
>> char(65+3)

ans =

D
```

And also note that the numbers representing characters come in a nice order:

```
>> char(33:100)

ans =

!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcd
```

...So all your characters in your original string can be 'pushed up one' just by adding 1 to their numerical representation. I need a hack to deal with the case of `9`->`0`, but apart from that all should be well.

---

**Your loop problem**

The main problem with your loop is that if none of the `if` statements ever execute, `j` is never incremented so the `while` is always met. Move `j=j+1` outside of the if statements to ensure it is always incremented.

The reason none of the `if` statements are met is because:

a) The first char in `str` is not any of the numbers 0-9,

and

b) `strcmpi` requires two strings as input, but you are giving a number and a string - i.e.:

```
>> strcmpi(2, '2')

ans =

     0
```

Comment: thanks, the first way actually helped alot
what i did with 9->0 is just using a for loop with condition to check and switch it, but it would be nice to know what is wrong with the first loop as well